# I want to remove ESXi hypervisor from a machine and make it completely bare metal? How can I do that?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hypervisor

I want to remove ESXi hypervisor from a machine and make it completely bare metal?  How can I remove ESXi hypervisor?

Comment: Just install whatever OS you want, and during installation process delete partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Get live linux distribution and remove all the partitions you find on disks. And you will get bare metal machine. On the boot disk you can also exec:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1024 count=1024
```

where `/dev/sda` is your boot disk